# What would be a single word for "un bookmark"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I bookmarked a site. I don't want to keep the bookmark anymore.

**So I go ahead and remove the bookmark.** What would be a better sentence?
Something like: "I **un-bookmarked** the site"

Comment: Why do you think *unbookmark* is not a good word here?

Comment: Not sure if "unbookmark" is a legal word.

Comment: @Raunak there are no word police

Answer (score 4):

### Unbookmark is a perfectly [cromulent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/what-does-cromulent-mean) word

We have [bookmark](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bookmark) which has been in use since 1985 in relation to computers and has the transitive verb forms of bookmark, bookmarked, bookmarking, or bookmarks and we have the time-honoured prefix [un](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/UN) meaning to do the opposite of. No hyphen though, un words don't do that.

Comment: The only question is, which to choose: unbookmark, debookmark, disbookmark, etc.  If we have assemble/disassemble, when you invent your new word, why not choose "disbookmark"?

Comment: I suspect un- is more productive than the alternatives, but you'd need to look at recently coined words to prove that - "unfriend" comes to mind.